# Kendo DateTimePicker Manual Entry

Tags: kendo-ui, datetimepicker

I'd like to be able to manually enter a date into the dateTime picker and have it persist to the control.

Example Code: http://jsfiddle.net/awDA4/39/

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div>
<input id="datepicker" style="width:200px" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#datepicker").kendoDateTimePicker();
});
```

Say you enter a date by hand into the control like '08/08/2013'

1. If you then post the form the start of time (01/01/0001) date is sent
2. If you pick a time from the time drop down it reverts to the current date

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

I thought about marking the input as readonly/disabled but surely you should be able to allow users to type a date by hand.

Comment: use change event and bind the date to the control

Comment: That's a good idea, but I don't see that the Kendo change event fires when you type something in the box. Are you thinking regular old .js change event?

Comment: yeah that's one way of dealing with this. not sure why Kendo Change event is not firing. Better continue with regular js change event

Comment: I'll give it a try & update with my results

Comment: you can add event to kendo-ui like this: $("#datetimepicker").data('kendoDateTimePicker').bind('change',function(){alert('oops');});

Comment: @hungdoan The change event will only fire IF the value is of an acceptable format. If you type say 'asfd', '1234' ect. Change won't be triggered

Comment: @AndrewWalters yeah, I forgot that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to include additional parseFormats when initializing the DateTimePicker

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#datepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    parseFormats: ["MMMM yyyy", "HH:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy"] //format also will be added to parseFormats
});
```

MM/dd/yyyy was added and I can now manually key in dates with that format